# dynamodb node aws-sdk simple getItem() call

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Folks, New to Javascript... trying to do simple dynamo queries from node:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var params = {
"TableName" : 'admins',
"Key" : [
      { "username" : { "S" : "foo" } },
    ],
}

 db.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log('error: '+ err);
    console.log(data);
    return next();
    res.send(data);
  });
 }
```

Output:

```
error: UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'username' found in params.Key['0']
```

Thanks!  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @hexacyanide Im weak in javascript.  I guess im asking for an example on how to do a simple db.getItem operation

Comment: cmag, you are still active, perhaps you could accept an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was trying to do it as it was suggested in the documentation, but also got errors.

At the end the following worked:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var db = new aws.DynamoDB({
  region: 'eu-central-1',
  maxRetries: 1
});

exports.handler = event => {
    return queryMyThings();
}

const queryMyThings = async (event) => { 
 var params = {
      Key: {
      "ColumnByWhichYouSearch": {
         S: "ValueThatYouAreQueriing"
        }
      }, 
      TableName: "YourTableName"
     };

    return await db.getItem(params).promise();

}
```

Answer (score 19):

Must follow the SDK and Docs, its simple:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html

```
var params = {
    AttributesToGet: [
      "password"
    ],
    TableName : 'foo',
    Key : { 
      "username" : {
        "S" : "bar"
      }
    }
  }

  db.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err); // an error occurred
      } 
    else {
      console.log(data); // successful response
      res.send(data);
      }
    return next();
  });
```

Comment: I have tried the above code but still i am able to get the solution there is no error as well as output,actually its not calling the callback function.can u help me for the solution.

Comment: not sure i can help without seeing your code. post a question and link?

Comment: @Cmag, There's an erroneous comma after the username key.

Comment: I can't get a function to run the same as @BhavikJoshi. I am curious how did you get around this issue.

Comment: I would check the json, make sure there are no trailing comas which are not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Here are great resources for DynamoDB using NodeJS:

- [Getting Started guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.html)
- [Documentaion and examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html)
- [If you're using the `DocumentClient`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html)