# Dynamo DB getItem with node js throwing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am new to Javascript and DynamoDB. I am trying to perform getitem using aws-sdk for javascript in nodejs. primary index of Dynamo table Cars is "name" a string.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region='eu-west-1';
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var params = {
TableName : 'Cars',
            Key : {
                    "name" : {
                            "S" : "Volkswagen Dasher"
                    },
            }
}

db.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                console.log(err); // an error occurred
                }
                else {
                console.log(data); // successful response
                }
                return next();
                });
```

On running the above .js file I am getting the following error.

```
 ubuntu@ubuntu:~/node$ node getItem.js  
 {}
 /home/ubuntu/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:30
             throw err;
                   ^ ReferenceError: next is not defined
     at Response.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/node/getItem.js:21:10)
     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:353:18)
     at Request.callListeners (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
     at Request.emit (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
     at Request.emit (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:595:14)
     at Request.transition (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:21:10)
     at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
     at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:37:9)
     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:597:12)
```

Plz help me out. Cheers!

Comment: If that is all of your code, you don't want that `return next()`. Just let it exit after logging.

Comment: Following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073991/dynamodb-node-aws-sdk-simple-getitem-call

Comment: That other question was using Express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad to see you're giving DynamoDB a try!  I'm not really sure I understand the context of your code, but if your goal is to make a simple GetItem call, you don't need the 'return next()' statement.  Given javascript's event driven nature, these callbacks are asynchronous and don't really "return" anything.  Instead, you should inspect the [response](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html) (data) and perform an action accordingly.

I.E.

```
dynamoDB.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
                     if (data) {
                        doSomethingWithItem(data.Item);
                     }
                 });
```

Also, if you're just starting out I would recommend taking a look at the [document-js-sdk](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk) which a wrapper on top of the original SDK to allow you to use literals such as "string" instead of {S: "string"}.

Comment: Thank you. Was not aware that next() method was not in-built in the SDK. Was following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073991/dynamodb-node-aws-sdk-simple-getitem-call